# Ошибка в цикле разбивает таблицу

Tags: javascript

Создаю таблицу в js коде, таблица рисуется не корректно.

Получается так:

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><tr>
   </tbody>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
```

т.е. одна строка выходит за границы `tbody`. Думаю где-то в цикле ошибка...

Тут полный код: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/fwxuf5ea/28/))

```js
'use strict';

function getRuLocaleWeekDay(computed_day) {
  return (computed_day + 6) % 7;
}

var calendarDate = new Date(),
  year = calendarDate.getFullYear(),
  month = calendarDate.getMonth(),
  presentDay = calendarDate.getDate(),
  lastDayMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate(),
  weekDay = ['Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб', 'Вс'],
  divTable = document.createElement('table'),
  newRow = divTable.insertRow(-1),
  newCell, firstWeekDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay(),
  monthName = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];

divTable.className = 'table';

var month_cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
month_cell.setAttribute('colspan', 7);
month_cell.className = 'title-month';
month_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(monthName[calendarDate.getMonth()]));

newRow = divTable.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0, I = weekDay.length; i < I; i++) {
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
  newCell.className = 'odd';
  newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(weekDay[i]));
}

newRow = divTable.insertRow(-1);
lastDayMonth = lastDayMonth + getRuLocaleWeekDay(firstWeekDay);

for (i = 1; i <= lastDayMonth; i++) {
  if (i % 7 == 1) {
    newRow = divTable.insertRow(-1);
  }
  var date = i - getRuLocaleWeekDay(firstWeekDay); //переменная минус 6 дней

  newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);

  if (presentDay == date) {
    newCell.className = 'present-day';
  }

  if (i <= getRuLocaleWeekDay(firstWeekDay)) {
    newCell.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    newCell.innerHTML = date;
  }

}

var lastDateWeek = getRuLocaleWeekDay(new Date(year, month, lastDayMonth - getRuLocaleWeekDay(firstWeekDay)).getDay());

for (var i = lastDateWeek; i < 6; i++) {
  newRow.insertCell(-1);
}

divTable.appendChild(newRow);
document.getElementById('calendar').appendChild(divTable);

var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (cells[i].innerHTML != '') {
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', selectDate);
  }
}

function selectDate() {
  if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
    this.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    this.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #5A5A5A;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  /*opacity:0.1;*/
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: show;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: show;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes show {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.table tr td:last-child {
  background: rgba(255, 105, 180, 0.2);
}
td {
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
td:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
td.odd {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.5);
}
.title-month {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td.present-day {
  background: rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
divTable.appendChild(newRow);
```

- 62 строчка в фиддле. удалите ее. дублируете последний ряд просто